# Match Email ID Before Inserting With VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 7101 email IDs in A1 in sheet 1. Now I want to insert New Email ID in Sheet2. I am going to create a user form and Before Inserting new email ID the user should check whether the email ID is present in Sheet1. if the email ID is present it shows me a msg box 'the email is already there'

How do I do that?

Comment: If this answer is correct for you, think to accept it for others people who might have this question

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet 1")

Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

Dim emailFound As Range
Set emailFound = rg.Find("foo@bar.com", lookin:=xlValues)

If Not emailFound Is Nothing Then MsgBox "The email is already there" 
[...]
```

It should do the trick.